# regex for Ebuild File Format

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to parse the Ebuild File Format based on [File Naming Rules](https://devmanual.gentoo.org/ebuild-writing/file-format/index.html).

Until now I came up with:

```
(?P<name>[a-z0-9_-]+)-(?P<major>[0-9]+)(\.(?P<minor>[0-9]+))?(\.(?P<micro>[0-9]+))?(?P<release>(_alpha|_beta))*(?P<status>(_pre|_rc\d+|_p\d+))(?P<revision>-r\d+)*
```

which doesn't do the job ([Regex examples](https://regex101.com/r/uF7CAD/4)).

I am unhappy, that my version expression contains the `.` in the group match and  *release* contains the char `_` in the match. In addition the *revision* finds '-r' chars instead of returning the number it self.

How could I fix my regular expression?

Comment: Try  https://regex101.com/r/uF7CAD/6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of quantifying named group patterns with the separators you may put the separator before the named group, wrap the separator and the named group with an optional non-capturing group and use `?` quantifier to match 1 or 0 occurrences rather than `*` (you do not expect repetitions of `release`, `alpha` etc.).

So the pattern can be

```
pattern = r'''(?x)                     # Free spacing (re.X/re.VERBOSE) mode on
^                                      # Start of string
 (?P<name>[a-z0-9_-]+)                 # Name group: 1+ lowercase ASCII letters, digits, _ and -
 -                                     # a - char
 (?P<major>[0-9]+)                     # Major group: 1+ digits
 (?:\.(?P<minor>[0-9]+))?              # . and Minor group: 1+ digits
 (?:\.(?P<micro>[0-9]+))?              # . and Micro group: 1+ digits
 (?:_(?P<release>alpha|beta))?         # _ and Release group: "alpha" or "beta"
 (?:_(?P<status>pre|(?:rc|p)[0-9]+))?  # _ and Status group: "pre" or "rc" / "p" followed with 1+ digits
 (?:-r(?P<revision>[0-9]+))?           # -r, Revision group: 1+ digits
$                                      # End of string
'''
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uF7CAD/8)

Answer (score 1):

You should put it out of the groups [like this](https://regex101.com/r/uF7CAD/5):

```
(?P<name>[a-z0-9_-]+)-(?P<major>[0-9]+)(?:\.(?P<minor>[0-9]+))?(?:\.(?P<micro>[0-9]+))?(?:_(?P<release>alpha|beta))*(?:_(?P<status>pre|rc\d+|p\d+))(?P<revision>-r\d+)*
                                                                  ^^                      ^                            ^
```